# Weird normal graph, what's happening?

Tags: probability-theory

This appears to be a very basic question for this Stack Exchange, but hopefully still welcome. I am a math teacher and wanted to write a program to demonstrate normal distributions. I wrote a simple code in Processing that essentially flips a coin a certain number of times and makes a histogram of the results:

```
int piles = 200;
int[] amounts = new int[piles];
int counter = 0;
int maximum = 2000;
void setup(){
  size(1000,1000);
  for(int i=0;i<piles;i++){
    amounts[i] = 0;
  }
}

void draw(){
  if(counter < maximum){
    int value = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<piles;i++){
      if((int)random(0,2) == 0){
        value++;
      }
    }
    amounts[value]++;
    for(int i=0;i<piles;i++){
      for(int k=0;k<amounts[i];k++){
        ellipse((1000*i+500)/piles,(1000*k+500)/piles,1000/piles,1000/piles);
      }
    }
    counter++;
  }
}
```

The strange thing is that the histogram always ends up being very "pointy". Does this happen because of the random() method, are normal distributions pointier than I thought, or am I missing something stupid?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZGqu.png

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "pointy"?  I can imagine a few possible meanings, and I want to make sure I'm answering the question you have in mind and not something of my own invention.  Have you tried increasing 2000 to a much larger number to see what you think of the shape then?

Comment: Generally coding questions are off-topic here.  Is it possible for you to describe the algorithm in a more concise, language-independent way?  For example, it's not clear what ellipse() does, or what language this is in, or what random() method you are using.

Comment: You can compute the actual probabilities of the experiment by summing binomial coefficients. You can then compare the results to what you actually get.

Comment: @D.W. It's in Java, though there are a lot of Processing specific methods. All it does is use Processing's "random" method to pick either 0 or 1 and repeats that for the number of piles you want to use (in this case 200). I included a picture, but I really just mean that there appears to be a much larger value in the center and much lower values in the extremes than I would expect, but maybe most normal curve graphs I've seen just have skewed axes.